# Div's scrolling out of sync

Tags: javascript, android, css, scroll

I have an issue with scrolling a wrapper div that contains two divs. When scrolling the wrapper horizontally, the header section and the content section is scrolling out of sync on Android devices. They do catch up, but you can see the delay.

I am using the default scrolling, `overflow-x:` auto on the wrapper and both of the elements are absolutely positioned with left and right set to 0 with heights etc.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Here is the code that I am working with:

```js
var divEditWrapper = document.createElement("div");
divEditWrapper.id = "divEditWrapper";
divEditWrapper.style.cssText = "bottom: 0px; left: 0px; overflow: hidden; overflow-x: auto;  position: absolute; right: 0px; top: 64px;";
divEdit.appendChild(divEditWrapper);

divDataHeaders = document.createElement("div");
divDataHeaders.style.cssText = "color: rgba(0,0,0,0.54); height: 54px; left: 0px; position: absolute; right: 0px; top: 0px; ";
divEditWrapper.appendChild(divDataHeaders);

divEditContent = document.createElement("div");
divEditContent.id = "divDataGridEditContent";
divEditContent.style.cssText = "bottom: 0px; overflow: hidden; overflow-y:auto; left: 0px; position: absolute; right: 0px; top: 54px;";
divEditWrapper.appendChild(divEditContent);
```

Comment: It'd be helpful to post your code so we can see if there's something you didn't mention

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I came back to this issue because I had the same issue in another project, but the solution did not work there, using : -webkit-transform: translateZ(0); webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; on the wrapper, resolved the issue.

Comment: I forgot to add, this issue seemed to be caused by the browser not allocating enough GPU, using the suggestion, it forces that.

Answer (score 0):

I had solved similar issue by styling the div(Whatever be applicable) with 
`.div{top:0; left:0; }`. In your case, try styling header div. It might work.
Thanks,

Comment: Hi, I implemented the suggestion, it did not work, but thanks for the answer.

Comment: One silly suggestion. Include css style `{float:left}` for each concerned div. Many a times, it worked for me.